# clang - shared_ptr fails to run its deleter

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, clang, shared-ptr

This code prints `0` (with no optimization) or `666` (with optimizations turned on) when built with `clang++ -std=c++11` (`-O3` yields `666`, which is what I would expect). When lambda is passed by universal reference the problem disappears.

FYI, GCC prints `666` on all the versions I've tested.

Is it a compiler bug or the code is incorrect?

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<void> onScopeExit(T f)
{
    return std::shared_ptr<void>((void*)1, [&](void *) {
        f();
    });
}

struct A {
  void f() {
    auto scopeGuard = onScopeExit([&]() { i = 666; }); //  [1]
    // ... (some work)
  } // (lambda [1] being ? called on scope exit)

  int i = 0;
};

A a;

int main() {
  a.f();
  std::cout << a.i << std::endl;
}
```

The compiler in question is:

```
Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior.  You capture `f` by reference in `onScopeExit` but once you return the `shared_ptr` from the function the deleter is now holding a dangling reference to `f`, since `f` went out of scope.  What you need to do is capture `f` by value, and then you won't have a dangling reference

```
template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<void> onScopeExit(T f)
{
    return std::shared_ptr<void>((void*)1, [=](void *) {
        f();
    });
}

struct A {
  void f() {
    auto scopeGuard = onScopeExit([&]() { i = 666; }); //  [1]
    // ... (some work)
  } // (lambda [1] being ? called on scope exit)

  int i = 0;
};

A a;

int main() {
  a.f();
  std::cout << a.i << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just one minor extra question: if I'd pass `f` by `T&&` and `std::forward` it into lambda would it be also OK? (or maybe better?)

Comment: @puhacz That should be okay.  You could also leave the function as it is now in the answer and replace `[=]` with `[f = std::move(f)]` so you move `f` into the lambda.  It's just a matter of what do you want to have happen when you pass an lvalue into `onScopeExit`.  Do you copy it, or do you hold a reference to it.  Taking a reference would only be bad if you return `scopeGuard` up out of the scope.